# Intellij 2022.1: echo command not working as expected

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently updated my intellij to 2022.1, and I observe that echo command is not working as expected.

On windows cmd:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
....\java\zulu11.56.19-ca-jdk11.0.15-win_x64
```

In intellij terminal:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%
```

It used to work fine in previous version of intellij.

Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Share your Preferences | Tools | Terminal. Is it configured to use cmd?

Comment: Check IntelliJ's Terminal Settings: Open IntelliJ and go to "File" -> "Settings" (or "Preferences" on macOS). In the settings window, navigate to "Tools" -> "Terminal" -> "Default Shell" and check if it is set to the correct shell (e.g., Command Prompt or PowerShell). You can also try changing the default shell to see if it resolves the issue